# Specs for creating sample set?

Tags: audio

I would like to create a set of audio samples for playback as a midi-controlled instrument. Thus: a sample for every key of the piano range, with multiple volume timbres for each note. I am able to create recordings at various specifications. My problem is finding a specification as to how a sample set is packaged so that it can be used by a standard DAW. Searching so far has not turned up any leads.

If there is a appropriate in another forum to try, I'd be happy to learn of it.

Comment: Also try asking over at: http://music.stackexchange.com   They answer a lot of midi sampler questions there.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this variant of stackexchange even existed.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner : Let me know, and I can migrate it there.  Please don't cross-post! :-)

Comment: This site seems more appropriate. The questions on the music site are more about music theory and practice, it seems to me, not oriented to programming or technical specs. If I did post there, it has vanished. I can't recall if I posted there or not. Maybe you or someone deleted it?

Answer (score 1):

[SoundFont 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoundFont) (SF2) sampled sound banks can be used in any digital audio workstation (DAW) software either natively or via a plug-in virtual instrument. It is an old format from the 16-bit Sound Blaster days but still widely supported, and satisfies your requirements of having key and velocity ranges. More recently there is the [SFZ](http://ariaengine.com/overview/sfz-format/) file format that is manually editable as a text file. You tell in the SFZ file which WAV files are to be used and how. There are also SF2 and SFZ editors and SF2→SFZ converters available.

Comment: Looks like this could be a good answer. I am seeing that different DAW's may have their own formats for this sort of thing. I'm really busy until midweek, will likely accept it at that time once I've confirmed I can work with this. Thanks. Will up vote it, meantime.